# in quicksort why do we start the decrement outside the array

Tags: java, quicksort

```
public class QuickSort {
    public static void sort(int[] a) {
        StdRandom.shuffle(a);
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] a, int left, int right) {
        if (right <= left) {
            return;
        }
        int j = partition(a, left, right);      
        sort(a, left, j - 1);
        sort(a, j + 1, right);
    }

    private static int partition(int[] a, int left, int right) {
        int i = left;
        int j = right+1;
        int pivot = a[left];
        while (true) {
            while (a[++i] < pivot) {
                if (i == right) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (a[--j] > pivot) {
                if (j == left) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i >= j) {
                break;
            }
            swap(a, i, j);
        }
        swap(a, left, j);
        return j;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 5, 3, 1, 34, 43, 5454};
        QuickSort.sort(a);
        show(a);

    }

    private static void show(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

in this example, the `int j = right+1` starts outside the array, so then we decrement by `a[--j]`

When I change it to `int j = right` and decrement by `a[j--]` the output is not the same. Probably something simple but been confused about for the past hour. I don't get why we don't just decrement starting at the last index of the array such as:

```
{4,3,6,1,9}

int j = right
```

so `j = array[4]` then we say `while... array[4--]` which would turn into `j=array[3]` right?

isn't this the same thing: `right+1 and --j` and to `right and j--`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines:

```
while (a[--j] > pivot) {
    if (j == left) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Expect the two values of `j` to be the same. If you change it to

```
while (a[j--] > pivot) {
    if (j == left) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The first referenced j, `a[j--]` will be one higher then the next j, `j == left`

If you wanted to make the change, you would have to change it to:

```
while (a[j--] > pivot) {
    if (j+1 == left) { //adding one back in
        break;
    }
}
```

My personal opinion is that the code was cleaner before, since starting one outside a range is common and understandable. Adding one back is is 'fiddly' and will make everyone question whether it is correct.

The clearest way to make your change might be:

```
while (a[j] > pivot) {
    if (j == left) {
        break;
    }
    j--; // waiting until the end to decrement
}
```

I would consider that pretty clean, and preferable to the original because you start with `int j = right`.

Comment: Thanks, I see now why we are starting outside. I got it to work without doing a right+1 but I am going to stick to the original

Answer (score 1):

The value of j is compared against in other places in the loop. If the counter started with `j = right`, after decrementing j with either `--j` or `j--` the value of j at those points will not be the same as if you started with `j = right+1`